# How to get the cause of ValidationError in discord.js without using stack?

Tags: typescript, validation, discord.js

If a Discord bot tries to register an invalid slash command using the library `discord.js 14.11.0`, a `ValidationError` is thrown. However, I couldn't find any property that would reveal the cause of the error without searching the stack. The problem is demostrated by the following example in TypeScript.

```
import { REST, Routes, SlashCommandBuilder } from "discord.js";
import { readFileSync } from "fs";
import { ValidationError } from "@sapphire/shapeshift";

const config = JSON.parse(readFileSync("./config.json", { encoding: "utf-8" }));
const rest = new REST().setToken(config.token);

try {
    await rest.put(
        Routes.applicationCommands(config.clientID), {
            body: [
                new SlashCommandBuilder()
                    .setName("command")
                    // Forgot description here
                    .toJSON()
        ]}
    );
} catch (e) {
    const error = e as ValidationError;

    // How to get the cause of the error (missing description)
    // without using stack?
    console.log(error.given); // undefined
    console.log(error.message); // Expected a string primitive
    console.log(error.name); // Error
    console.log(error.validator); // s.string

    if (
        error.stack?.includes("Expected a string primitive") &&
        error.stack?.includes("validateDescription")
    ) console.log("You forgot to add a description to your command!");
}
```

As you can see, number of properties on the error are useless in detecting the cause of the error. What I found that works is to search the stack and try to determine the cause from it. Here is an example of a stack from this error.

```
node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:1715   
    return typeof value === "string" ? Result.ok(value) : Result.err(new ValidationError("s.string", "Expected a string primitive", value));

ValidationError: Expected a string primitive
    at StringValidator.handle (node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:1715:70)
    at StringValidator.parse (node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:212:88)
    at validateDescription (node_modules\@discordjs\builders\dist\index.js:1408:25)
    at validateRequiredParameters (node_modules\@discordjs\builders\dist\index.js:1422:3)
    at MixedClass.toJSON (node_modules\@discordjs\builders\dist\index.js:2302:5)
    at file:///index.js:9:14
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:194:25) {
  validator: 's.string',
  given: undefined
}
```

Searching the stack is not performance friendly because the stack can be long and the search strings don't have to be at the top or can be missing. Surely there has to be a better way to determine the cause of the error.

Comment: Look in `message` instead of `stack` and use the switch/case

Comment: @Akxe `error.message` contains `Expected a string primitive`. So I cannot determine if it's a missing description or name from it.

Comment: @NoobDev `error.name` outputs `Error`. How is this supposed to help me?

Comment: It seems like this is not really possible at the moment. I removed my answer because even with `ValidationError` there is not enough information available for your use case... There is an open issue at GitHub about basically the same problem you are having: https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/8837